# discord.py - remove role after stopped playing a game

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want the bot to remove role after member stops playing the game.

When member's not playing a game, there is no `game = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]` anymore.
so when trying to remove role it can't find `game[0].name` I think.

How do i fix this?

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    game = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    
    if game:
        game_name = game[0].name
        role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
        if role == None:
            await after.guild.create_role(name=game_name, hoist=True, mentionable=True)
        await after.add_roles(role)
        
    elif before.activities and not game:
        game_name = game[0].name
        role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
        if role in after.roles: 
            await after.remove_roles(role)
```

> ```
>   File "C:\Users\BUGA\Documents\VSCODE\Python Projects\activity role\main.py", line 35, in on_member_update
>     game_name = game[0].name
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue happens because you are only checking the `Activity` in the `after`, so if you try to get the name of the game from the `after`, of course it will return `None` after the user stops playing it, yet you try to access the name of the game doing:

```
game_name = game[0].name
```

In the second if you should check the name of the game in the before, something like this:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    game = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    
    if game:
        game_name = game[0].name
        role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
        if role == None:
            await after.guild.create_role(name=game_name, hoist=True, mentionable=True)
            role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
        await after.add_roles(role)
    elif before.activities and not game:
        # We get the game frim the before
        game = [i for i in before.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
        # Only remove role if he was actually playing a game before
        if game:
            game_name = game[0].name
            role = discord.utils.get(before.guild.roles, name=game_name)
            if role in before.roles: 
                await after.remove_roles(role)
```

Comment: when `role == None` after it creates the role, it gives me this error ```in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'``` and it doesnt give the role but the role is created. if I exit game and run game again it gives me the role. I tried to add delay in between creating role and adding role but it's still the same

Comment: @Rashid I have edited my answer to solve that issue. For the next time create a new question if you have a different question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to remove a role from a user once he *stops* playing a game, you should check which games he was playing in `before`, since that still holds the game he was playing.

You need to get `game` twice, or rather, split it into `game_before` and `game_after`.

Something like:

```py
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    game_before = [i for i in before.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]
    game_after = [i for i in after.activities if str(i.type) == "ActivityType.playing"]

    if game_after:
        game_name = game_after[0].name
        role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
        if role == None:
            await after.guild.create_role(name=game_name, hoist=True, mentionable=True)
        await after.add_roles(role)     
    elif game_before:
        game_name = game_before[0].name
        role = discord.utils.get(after.guild.roles, name=game_name)
        if role in after.roles: 
            await after.remove_roles(role)
```